# Apache Chemistry - Java: Random "Unauthorized" exception when uploading documents to SharePoint 2010

Tags: java, sharepoint-2010, cmis, apache-chemistry

I have a service which connects from Lotus Notes to SharePoint 2010 and uploads pdf documents.

I have noticed when running larger job of ~14 000  documents that "Unauthorized" exception is thrown every 5 - 10 minutes which forces my code to stop and resume upload.

I'm using atompub and ntlm login in format [domain][username].

Do I need to refresh session before each document creation?
Enable cookies? Maybe I'm timing out. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Anything helpful in the SharePoint logs? If you switch it to uploading to another CMIS server, eg Alfresco, does that go through without errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the NTLM authentication. Enabling cookies mitigates the issue, but I would recommend a different authentication method.

Comment: Ill try with cookies and will let you know.

Comment: I have enabled cookies but it did not help much. However when code is changed not to abort process but to skip document, next document is uploaded without error. So it seems like connection is refreshed.

Is there a way of manual connection restore on CmisUnauthorizedException?

Comment: The problem is that the first POST request over a new socket fails with NTML. Technically, it would be possible to send a HEAD or GET request before each POST, but that would be additional overhead and OpenCMIS doesn't support that. It's very unlikely that OpenCMIS will ever fully support NTML because NTMLv1 is considered insecure. You should really think about a different authentication method.

Comment: By other you mean Standard? There are NONE, NTLM and STANDARD.
Will standard authentication work with Sharepoint 2010, 2013 and Alfresco?

Comment: There's one more issue. Domain users. If there is SharePoint server on the domain then all registered users are automatically logged in. I can even log on over CMIS with blank credentials. How can I make sure that connection is really done over plain/standard method? I'm asking this because I can set standard authentication but I'm not sure will it have any effect and it will potentially repeat Unauthorized exception.

Comment: Standard authentication is HTTP basic authentication. Kerberos is another option but very difficult to set up. OpenCMIS also allow to plug in you own authentication code, but that's something you have to implement on your own.